# Compare a list with multiple lists inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to compare a list with multiple lists stored in a list and get the average correctness of my data. **I want to compare one list with 35 lists(for my project) but i've simplified to comparing one list with three lists to make it easier to understand.**
Here's what i've done so far,

```py
def get_accuracy(a, b):
    # Initialize variable to get sum 
    total = 0.0
    # Range of 35 because i have 35 lines of data stored in csv file
    for i in range(35):
        # Get the number of matching zeros and ones between 2 lists
        f = sum(a != b for a, b in zip(a, b))
        # Divide the number of matched zeros and ones with length of the shorter list
        if len(a) > len(b):
            percentage = f / len(b) * 100
        else:
            percentage = f / len(a) * 100
        total += percentage
    #Return total/35 to get the average correctness after comparing with 35 lists
    return total / 35

l1=[1,0,1,0,0]
l2=[[1,0,1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1,0]]
res=get_accuracy(l1,l2)
#Expected answer should be 73.33%
print(res)
```

I've explained what job every line of code does to complete my comparison. What changes do i have to make to compare `l1` with every lists in `l2` to get an average matching correctness?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simpler example to get list similarity in percentage for you:

```
# initialize lists 
test_list1 = [1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7] 
test_list2 = [7, 11, 12, 8, 9] 
  
# printing original lists 
print("The original list 1 is : " + str(test_list1)) 
print("The original list 2 is : " + str(test_list2)) 
  
# Percentage similarity of lists 
# using "|" operator + "&" operator + set() 
res = len(set(test_list1) & set(test_list2)) / float(len(set(test_list1) | set(test_list2))) * 100
  
# printing result 
print("Percentage similarity among lists is : " + str(res))
```

If for you it is ok to use a library difflib's sequence matcher makes it even easier to get a similarity ratio:

```
import difflib
sm=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,a,b)
sm.ratio()
```

A final version using difflib could look like this:

```
import difflib

def get_accuracy(a,b):
    result = 0.0
    for list_contained in b:
        sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, list_contained)
        result += sm.ratio()
    return result / len(b)

l1=[1,0,1,0,0]
l2=[[1,0,1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1,0]]
res=get_accuracy(l1,l2)
print(res)
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-percentage-similarity-of-lists/)

Comment: Hello, did you have a moment to check my reply? If it was useful for you please consider upvoting it and / or choosing it as final answer. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

assuming your code works for a single list, this should work.

```
def get_accuracy(a, b):
    sum = 0
    length = len(b)
    for list_in_b in b:
      # Initialize variable to get sum 
      total = 0.0
      # Range of 35 because i have 35 lines of data stored in csv file
      for i in range(35):
         # Get the number of matching zeros and ones between 2 lists
         f = sum(a != b for a, b in zip(a, list_in_b))
         # Divide the number of matched zeros and ones with length of the shorter list
         if len(a) > len(list_in_b):
            percentage = f / len(list_in_b ) * 100
         else:
            percentage = f / len(a) * 100
         total += percentage
      sum += total/35
     
    #Return total/35 to get the average correctness after comparing with 35 lists
    return sum / length
```

Comment: I've tried it with `l1=[1,0,1,0,0]   l2=[[1,0,1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1,0]]` and the result is 26.67% instead of 73.33% haha It's fine, i think the only problem is either the addition and division for `sum` or `percentage`

Comment: I've edited the code, I understood your question as 35 lists with 35 items in it, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
f = sum(i != j for i, j in zip(a, b[i]))
```